# Conditional formating in word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, conditional-statements, field

I am distributing some variables from excel to word. Now, I would like to put a conditional formatting in some fields. The normal situation that is working fine is this field:

{DOCVARIABLE AB*MERGEFORMAT}

Now, I want to apply condition to AB. For example, if AB < 1 it is highlighted as green and if it is AB>1 it highlighted as red. I tried different variations, but all of them was wrong. For example, 2 of them are these:

1-   {If {DOCVARIABLE AB*MERGEFORMAT}> "1" {DOCVARIABLE AB*MERGEFORMAT} {DOCVARIABLE AB*MERGEFORMAT}}

2-   {If <<DOCVARIABLE AB*MERGEFORMAT>> > "1" {DOCVARIABLE AB*MERGEFORMAT} {DOCVARIABLE AB*MERGEFORMAT}}

And I am highlighting the middle part as red and the last part as green. But it gives me the error that the operation is unknown, so the if function is not written in a proper way.

Comment: There is no such thing as conditional formatting in Word. You will need to write your own code to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hoped that it can work in this way.  The VBA code is in Excel, and variables are compiling as a report in a Word file. Is there any way that I can put conditional formatting in that code, and it will apply to word?

Comment: See, for example: *Conditionally Format Mailmerge Output, Conditionally Shade Table Cells* and *Conditionally Colour/Shade Numeric Output Ranges* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html. See also: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16505-change-color-according-dropdown-selection.html#post47254

Answer (score 2):

Although conditional formatting does not exist in Word it is possible to approximate it for very simple conditions. For further information see the documentation for [IF field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-if-field-9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e)

[image]

Comment: @NavidNikraftar - please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)